# Conditional replacement within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I am using a considerably big dataframe `histdf` (20M, 3). The fields are `Visitor_ID`, `content` and `time`. The dataframe will be used for an URL recommendation system, where `Visitor_ID` is a unique visitor identification, content is a visited URL and time is the time stamp.

With this structure, there are multiple URLs per unique visitor, but there are visitors that should be discarded because they won't produce important information (i.e. they visit too few URLs).

Thus, I created a new variable called `user_visits` , with the count of rows per unique value in `histdf.Visitor_ID`, and then I filtered it by higher than 10 count:

```py
user_visits = histdf.Visitor_ID.value_counts()
mask_user = user_visits > 10
```

`mask_user` is a pandas series. The index are the Visitor_ID and the values are Boolean (True if there were higher than 10 rows with that Visitor_ID in the original dataframe).

Now I want to add a new column `heavyuser` in `histdf` with the True or False values from `mask_user`.

What I did so far was setting values in the dataframe using this code:

```py
for index in histdf.index:
    temp = histdf.loc[index, 'Visitor_ID']
    temp2 = mask_user[temp]
    histdf.set_value(index, 'heavyuser', temp2)
```

This is kind of doing the job. Quite faster than using iterrows or other kind of iterations by rows. However, it is still slow, at more than 1 hour processing time.

I was wondering if there is some other option with better performance. The summary would be reading the number of rows per individual `Visitor_ID`, if those rows are fewer than a threshold (10 in this case), either put False in a new dataframe column or eliminate the rows altogether.

I'd appreciate any hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first instinct to extract the Visitor ID's of heavy users was good, but you don't need to iterate over your dataframe once you have them.

Here is how you could do it :

```
histdf = pd.DataFrame({'Visitor_ID':[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3], 
                   'content ': ["url" + str(x) for x in range(6)], 
                   'time':["timestamp n° " + str(x) for x in range(6)]}) 

# At first we consider that no user is a heavy user
histdf['heavy user'] = False

# Then we extract the ID's of heavy users
user_visits = histdf.Visitor_ID.value_counts()
id_heavy_users = user_visits[user_visits > 1].index

# Finally we consider those users as heavy users in the corresponding column
histdf.loc[histdf['Visitor_ID'].isin(id_heavy_users), 'heavy user'] = True
```

Output:

```
  Visitor_ID content             time  heavy user
0           1     url0  timestamp n° 0        True
1           1     url1  timestamp n° 1        True
2           2     url2  timestamp n° 2        True
3           2     url3  timestamp n° 3        True
4           2     url4  timestamp n° 4        True
5           3     url5  timestamp n° 5       False
```

---

If you just want to keep the heavy users like you mentionned at the end of your question you can do it without creating a third column like so :

```
histdf = pd.DataFrame({'Visitor_ID':[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3], 
                   'content ': ["url" + str(x) for x in range(6)], 
                   'time':["timestamp n° " + str(x) for x in range(6)]}) 

user_visits = histdf.Visitor_ID.value_counts()
id_heavy_users = user_visits[user_visits > 1].index

heavy_users = histdf[histdf['Visitor_ID'].isin(id_heavy_users)]

In [1] : print(heavy_users)
Out[1] :    Visitor_ID content             time
0           1     url0  timestamp n° 0
1           1     url1  timestamp n° 1
2           2     url2  timestamp n° 2
3           2     url3  timestamp n° 3
4           2     url4  timestamp n° 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just for the sake of testing, I ran a sample with a subset and the projection was it would take ~75 days to run the whole dataset with a conventional loop (0.3s per iteration, 20M total rows). My flawed solution was faster, but still very slow, at ~1 hour calculation time. vleimaistre's proposal ran in ~3.6s, and it was more than adequate to fulfill the requirement.

I appreciate your help a lot.